# How to solve 'Tensorial' equations?

Tags: differential-geometry, matrix-equations, tensors

I am trying to solve the following equation for the matrix of 16 components ${\dfrac{\partial{x^\alpha}}{\partial{x^{\mu '}}}}$ with $\alpha, \mu '$ $\in$ {${0,1,2,3}$}:

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial{x^{\alpha}}}{\partial{x^{\mu '}}}\displaystyle\frac{\partial{x^{\beta}}}{\partial{x^{\nu '}}} g_{\alpha \beta} - \delta_{\mu '}^{\alpha}\delta_{\nu '}^{\beta} g_{\alpha \beta} =0$

Where $g_{\alpha \beta }$ is a given specific tensor (actually the metric) which is completely known and unique. Also, I have used Einstein summation convention. The unprimed and primed indices represent components of the tensorial quantities in coordinate set-ups $O$ and $O'$ respectively.

I know that if the above-stated equality had been an identity then I would have cancelled out the metric component terms. But here, since this is not an identity but an equation, I can't do that. (Notice that Einstein summation is implied.) In other words, we don't know a priori that this equality is valid under general coordinate transformation but rather we have to find the transformations under which this equality is valid. So, how do I approach this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're treating $P^\alpha_{\mu'} = \dfrac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x^{\mu'}}$ as the unknown, this is just the linear algebra problem

$$ P^T g P = g. $$

Since $g$ is symmetric and non-degenerate, there is some invertible matrix $Q$ such that $g = Q^T \eta Q$ where $\eta$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\pm 1$. Substituting this and rearranging we get

$$ Q^{-T}P^TQ^T\ \eta\ QPQ^{-1} = (QPQ^{-1})^T\ \eta\ QPQ^{-1}=\eta.$$

This is true exactly when $QPQ^{-1}$ lies in the indefinite orthogonal group  associated to $\eta$; e.g. $O(3,1)$ when $g$ is Lorentzian. Thus you could write the solution space as $P \in O(g) = Q^{-1} O(\eta) Q$.

Comment: $g$ is not positive definite. It is the metric of a pseudo-Riemannian space if you wish.

Comment: @Electrodynamist: edited. The equation $P^T g P = g$ just means that $P$ preserves the bilinear form $g$, which is the characterizing property of $g$-orthogonal transformations.

Comment: Pardon me but how did you reduce the given equation to $P^TgP=g$?

Comment: Okay! I get it. I typed my previous comment before reading your last comment. Anyway, I am keeping the question open for now in order to try some other perspectives at the problem if someone might have. ;-)

Comment: What if I try to solve the equation with one more rank? i.e., 
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial{x^{\alpha}}}{\partial{x^{\mu '}}}\displaystyle\frac{\partial{x^{\beta}}}{\partial{x^{\nu '}}}\displaystyle\frac{\partial{x^{\gamma}}}{\partial{x^{\rho '}}} g_{\alpha \beta \gamma} - \delta_{\mu '}^{\alpha}\delta_{\nu '}^{\beta}\delta_{\rho '}^{\gamma} g_{\alpha \beta \gamma} =0$

Comment: @Electrodynamist: I believe that will depend very much on the structure of $g$. You saw in my answer that in the rank-two case there are many solutions - the only reason I was able to give such a succinct answer is because we have a standard name for the group of transformations preserving a quadratic form. I didn't really "solve" the equation in the sense of inverting anything. Here you're looking for the group of linear transformations preserving a trilinear form.

Comment: $g$ is completely symmetric just like in the previous case. Would that suffice? I am afraid not!

Comment: @Electrodynamist: as far as I know there is no nice classification of symmetric trilinear forms so there's no analog of reducing to studying the diagonal $\pm 1$ case. For the simple example $dx_1^3 + \cdots + dx_n^3$ I think there are only finitely many symmetries. If you really want to know I suggest you open a new question.